# Matlab - Referencing all images from the folder

Tags: string, image, matlab

I have 1000 bitmap images in my folder and I would like to put their names in an array of string as following

```
 ImageNameArray={'firstImage.bmp','second.bmp','third.bmp', . . . }
```

However each image has its own unique name. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`dir`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), which produces a struct array with `name` and other fields. You can pick that field and generate a cell array with all names:

```
files = dir('path\to\folder\*.bmp'); %// struct array
imageNameArray = {files.name}; %// cell array
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, appreciate it